# Protecting certain fields in a dynamic table

Tags: php, mysql

I have used a describe statement and converted my code to be dynamic . So each and every field in the Table is displayed to the user(since I have used the describe statement) . can anyone tell me , How can I make a few fields not to be shown to the user ?

For example 
Say I have a table by name Table1

Fields are Field1 Field2 Field3 Filed4 Field5

I have used Describe Table1;

I do not want the field 3 and field4 to appear to the user

can anyone help me on this please ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you make an exclusion list for what columns shouldn't be shown, then not show those?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be better off using the "SHOW COLUMNS" syntax: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-columns.html

e.g.

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM Table1 WHERE Field NOT IN ('Field3', 'Field4');
```